# Rolling a die to get a sum of at least 300

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

The original question: Suppose you are throwing a fair-six-sided die, find the probability that at least 80 rolls are necessary to have the sum exceed 300.

My solution: Let $X_i$ be the result of ith row, since they are iid and $\mathbb{E}X=7/2$ and $\sigma_X=\sqrt{35/12}$, by central limit theorem. $$\mathbb{P}(\geq 80 \ \text{rolls to get} \geq 300)=\mathbb{P}(79 th \text{ rolls receive} < 300 )=\mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^{79}X_i<300)$$
$$\mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^{79}X_i<300)=\mathbb{P}(\overline{X}<\frac{300}{79})\approx \mathbb{P}(Z<\frac{\frac{300.5}{79}-3.5}{\sqrt{\frac{35/12}{79}}})=0.92$$
I used Central Limit Theorem in last approach.

I tried a different approach, let $Y$ be the r.v denoting the number of times to receive at least 300. Then clearly $50\leq Y\leq 300$. We just need $\mathbb{P}(Y\geq 80)$ and $\mathbb{E}Y=\frac{300}{3.5}$, is there a way to find $Var(Y)$ and can this be approximated using normal distribution. I think the intuition is yes, because getting an anticipated number can be seen as a success. This is a almost binomail distribution which can be approximated by normal distrbution. Can anyone help me to solve this problem in this approach.

Comment: Note that *"to have the sum exceed $300$"* is not the same as *"to have the sum reach at least $300$"* (and your equality $P(\ge80\dots)=P(79th\dots)$ is thus incorrect). With the former I get $p\simeq0.943042$ (that is, $P(\sum_{i=1}^{79}X_i\le300)$), and with the latter $p\simeq0.935083$ ($P(\sum_{i=1}^{79}X_i\lt300)$). Apart from the final approximation of the fraction, the result is exact, computed by $78$ successive convolutions. You may also find this by expanding the polynomial $P^{79}$ with $P=\frac16(X+X^2+\cdots+X^6)$ then the sum of coefficients of $X^i$ with $i<300$ or $i\le300$.

Answer (score 2):

> find the probability that at least 80 rolls are necessary to have the sum exceed 300.

Using CLT and the necessary Continuity Correction Factor you get

$$\mathbb{P}[Y\le 300]=\mathbb{P}\left[Z\le \frac{300.5-79\cdot\frac{7}{2}}{\sqrt{79\cdot\frac{35}{12}}}  \right]=\Phi(1.5811)\approx94.31\%$$

Comment: Thanks, I edited the problem, but what about the other approach